# Mysql : last five records if having same value

Tags: php, mysql

I searched a lot and tried many queries but not getting satisfied answer. So like to ask.

I am looking for last **5 records from mysql table if having same value** otherwise not.

Something like `if col_n is having same value x from last 5 records then count otherwise not`. But I am not able to figure out how to write query for this ?

```
SELECT count(col_n) 
from track if(last five col_n = 'ok') 
WHERE col_a = 'value1' AND col_b = 'value2'
```

[enter mysql table records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqnBc.png)

Comment: show the queries you tried please

Comment: Please write a query which you tried then we try to modify that.

Comment: I never wrote if statement in mysql so have no idea what to write ?

Comment: `from last 5 records` ... this only makes sense with regard to some order in your table.  Please add some sample data to make this a real question.

Comment: Okay @JhonA, please try my answer

Comment: i attached an image of mysql table from my phpmyadmin. Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM   demo  ORDER by id DESC
      LIMIT 5
    ) AS p
  JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM   
        ( SELECT 1 
          FROM   demo
          LIMIT 5
        ) AS tmp
    ) AS c
    ON c.cnt = 5 WHERE p.name='x'
```

Comment: please check i attached an image of mysql table

Comment: Hey, @JhonA, please try this query as I updated my answer

Comment: Sorry Gufran Hasan , not working. First 2-3 trials it shows result but after that it is giving no results i tested and checked every variables are right.

Comment: I got another solution with the help of PHP , to retrieve all last 5 records of the user and check if they are same. If same then do action otherwise not. So if there is no direct solution through mysql command then PHP i will implement.